# Cylinder using only tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have just about what I want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,font=\footnotesize]
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\draw[->] (-0.25,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25)--(0,1.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[above right]{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$};;
\draw (0,0) node[below left]{$0$};
\draw (1,3pt)--(1,-3pt) node[below]{$1$};
\draw[red,dashed] (0.5,0)--(0.5,0.71);
\draw (0.5,3pt)--(0.5,-3pt) node[below]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,font=\footnotesize]
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\draw[->] (-0.25,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25)--(0,1.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[above right]{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$};;
\draw (0,0) node[below left]{$0$};
\draw (1,3pt)--(1,-3pt) node[below]{$1$};
\filldraw[color=black,fill=red!40] (.45,0) rectangle (.55,.71);
\draw[fill=black] (.5,0) node[below]{$(x,0)$} circle (1pt);
\draw[fill=black] (.5,.71) node[above]{$(x,\sqrt{x})$} circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,font=\footnotesize]
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!50] (1,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=1];
\draw[fill=red!40] (.45,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=.71];
\draw[fill=red!40] (.55,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=.71];
\draw[->] (-0.25,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.25)--(0,1.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[above right]{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$};;
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)}) ;
\draw (0,0) node[below left]{$0$};
\draw (1,3pt)--(1,-3pt) node[below]{$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Which gives me these images.

[image]

The third image is where I need help. The two red ellipses need to be combined to create a cylinder when the rectangle in the second figure is revolved about the x-axis.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

P.S. I'd like to do this strictly in tikz, pgf, not another pgf package.

Thanks.

P.S. Looks like I have a technique that works, changing the third picture to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,font=\footnotesize]
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!50] (1,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=1];
\draw[fill=red!40] (.45,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=.71];
\fill[red!40] (.45,-.71) rectangle (.55,.71);
\draw[fill=red!40] (.55,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=.71];
\draw (.45,.71)--(.55,.71);
\draw (.45,-.71)--(.55,-.71);
\draw[->] (-0.25,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.25)--(0,1.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[above right]{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$};;
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)}) ;
\draw (0,0) node[below left]{$0$};
\draw (1,3pt)--(1,-3pt) node[below]{$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the resulting picture.

[image]

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: David, would you consider writing a self-answer for this question? You could simply copy-paste your latest code and output sections.

Answer (score 2):

This is David's solution (which was edited into the question) as an answer:

**The TikZ Code**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,font=\footnotesize]
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!50] (1,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=1];
\draw[fill=red!40] (.45,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=.71];
\fill[red!40] (.45,-.71) rectangle (.55,.71);
\draw[fill=red!40] (.55,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=.71];
\draw (.45,.71)--(.55,.71);
\draw (.45,-.71)--(.55,-.71);
\draw[->] (-0.25,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.25)--(0,1.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[above right]{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$};;
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)}) ;
\draw (0,0) node[below left]{$0$};
\draw (1,3pt)--(1,-3pt) node[below]{$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**The Output**

[image]